# Is Microsoft SQL Server fast enough to be used as cache for an API?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, redis

Basically, without giving too much details, I need to make an API, that, as far as I can tell, is to be comprised of two parts. I have been told the API could be accessed by as many as 30.000 concurrent users, so my main concern is how do I make it fast enough. The two parts are as follows:

1. There will be a server that uses a SDK to retrieve data from a third party. Exactly what data isn't important, but it will be a constant heavy flow of data. Now, this server will take the data and put it in a database that will be used as cache.
2. Once the data is in the database, another server program that will run on the same machine as the database (not sure this is the right decision) will subscribe to the database changes. Once new data is available, it will send it to the subscribers, depending on what hub they subscribed to. Obviously, different hubs mean different data streams, depending on what they want. I've been told that also once in a while, I should back-up the in-memory database (the cache) to a PostgreSQL server just in case something happens, which seems sensible.

I have to use .NET Core to build this project, this cannot be changed. Next, I thought it was a good idea to use SignalR to deliver the data from the cache to the clients, as it seems perfectly fit for this. But when it comes to what database to use for the cache, things get a little bit blurry for me. Initially, I wanted to use Redis, and whenever new data comes in, put it in a stream data structure in Redis. The second program could subscribe to the streams in a blocking-way, and as new data becomes available, send it to the clients. Seems pretty easy, but it's not. Still, I think I could make it work as Redis already has everything I need to make this work in terms of commands available.

Another possible solution is to use old reliable Microsoft SQL Server to store the data, and use `SqlDependency` from Entity Framework to subscribe to a particular table and look for changes. While this does seem more elegant, I am worried it will greatly damage my speed, so I am working to find a better architecture. I have less than a year programming experience (excluding what I did in college). I am open to any suggestions. I was also thinking of having more than one cache database to work with, but I don't even know how that would work exactly in terms of updating the cache. I am seriously lost here, as I've never something close to this size before.

Comment: There's no way to know this for sure without performing some testing, and there are several variables that will affect your results: the speed of your network, the kind of processor, how much RAM is installed, etc.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that has crossed my mind, and will do some testing for sure once I build a minimum-working api. But I am also looking to see if the architecture I proposed is any good, and if you can spot any possible bottlenecks.

Comment: The 2 things that stick out to me: This is mostly a scaling issue. Scaled *properly* whatever properly might be as Robert mentioned, SQL Server should be fine, maybe also with your in memory cache. Secondly though, why backup to Postgres? Seems a PITA to manage two SQL infrastructures...

Comment: That said, I've never seen SQL Server used this way.  30,000 *concurrent* users sounds like a lot (akin to Facebook scale); my instinct is to say "You aren't gonna need it."  Use sensible development techniques for your application so that caching (Redis or otherwise) can be easily dropped in later, if and when it actually becomes needed.

Comment: Alas, SO isn't really designed to answer this sort of question. The simple answer to your questions "yes; SQL server can handle it" but the actual answer you seek and the associated nuts and bolts of it are off topic for StackOverflow because you seem to be asking a "what is the best..." and that requires opinion rather than fact based answers

Comment: There are free and paid Stress Testing applications available (take a peek at https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/04/free-sql-server-load-testing-tools/ )   That said, I sincerely doubt you will ever approach 30,000 truly concurrent users

Comment: sql server can handle it, provided you also throw the needed amount of resources to it. try to load your system without caching and if it is not acceptable you can add something like redis. If you are using SignalR you can also use redis as a backplane for multiple hubs to communicate and also use pub sub to update the hubs when new data is inserted in redis and te hubs will in turn notify the connected clients via web socket.

Comment: 30,000 concurrent users could mean radically different things. 30,000 players in a MMO updating their positions every second is quite a bit different from 30,000 people browsing a forum and loading a page every minute.

Comment: Your scenario suggests to me that you should be looking into queueing platforms, like e.g. Kafka or RabbitMQ, but it's going to be highly dependent on the specifics which is better. If I were you I would be looking into building a couple of proofs of concept.